# How to export Reports in Microsoft Access in a specific manner

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a client that reads their reports in Microsoft access...the woe is she tries to export the report to an excel file by right clicking on the report and going to export->Excel

This works, but the labels are not in the right order etc... in the report they are right..but in the exported file they need more data (or she wants more).  I have to say I am perplexed how to somehow intercept the export and write my own xls file out based on the query that generated the report... or some other way?  Maybe another report that is generated that is for the sole purpose of exporting that has the columns in the final xls file the way she wants...I am not a guru at this just know enough to be dangerous so I am not sure what the best method to attack this is and get it where the exported report as an excel file has the columns she wants.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options one is more efficient and one more flexible:

More efficient:
Write the query to a CSV file file using IO statements

More flexible:
Build the Excel file cell by cell using an Excel object. Of course you can use loops and make it generic so it will work with any query passed as a parameter

Comment: okay thanks I will investigate this.  I didn't realize how light i am on Microsoft Office knowledge so I will have to research both these are... as I don't know the vocabulary here (query to csv file using IO statements?)  like would that be ran under a button on a form or something?  basically making it where they dont have to run an export from the report but hit a button and it does it.